# Deploying Ionic2 on Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, ionic2

I am trying to deploy my ionic2 app on Heroku. I looked at these sites:

- http://blog.ionic.io/one-mean-ionic-2-todo-app-on-heroku-part-1/
- https://www.joshmorony.com/building-a-review-app-with-ionic-2-mongodb-node/
- https://devdactic.com/deploying-ionic-to-heroku/

and created a `server.js` file:

```
var express  = require('express');
var app      = express();                               // create our app w/ express
var morgan = require('morgan');             // log requests to the console (express4)
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');    // pull information from HTML POST (express4)
var cors = require('cors');

app.use(morgan('dev'));                                         // log every request to the console
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({'extended':'true'}));            // parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.json());                                     // parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json({ type: 'application/vnd.api+json' })); // parse application/vnd.api+json as json
// app.use(methodOverride());
app.use(cors());

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'DELETE, PUT');
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
});

app.use(express.static('www'));
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 5000);
app.listen(app.get('port'), function () {
  console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

Since I have no models and no DB at this time, I excluded mongo and mongoose.

The server runs fine when I run it on my local machine via `npm start` but when I run it on heroku, I get:

```
Cannot GET /
```

on the page. Heroku Logs shows:

```
2017-01-04T19:56:59.385666+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2017-01-04T19:57:00.546815+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=hrmghp-companion.herokuapp.com request_id=4c010120-3dce-4f99-b31c-99dc0883f314 fwd="108.44.230.178" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=49ms status=404 bytes=364
2017-01-04T19:57:00.549928+00:00 app[web.1]: GET / 404 19.924 ms - 13
```

Am I missing something in my `server.js` file?

**Edit:**
I found the issue. I had `www/` in my `.gitignore` file. I assumed that it would rebuild the app when deploying to heroku? Is this not how it works?

Comment: Thanks for the www/ tip. I guess it's this because I'm using Heroku automatic deployment after code is pushed on a Github branch.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't add `www` to your repository. You don't want to keep track of all those files. Instead, include `"postinstall": "ionic-app-scripts build"` in the `scripts` section of your package.json. This will rebuild the app and regenerate the `www` folder for you on Heroku.

Comment: This is the better way of doing it. My way is the "quick and dirty" way, but is ultimately wrong. Don't add www to the repo.

Comment: This did not work for me. I ended up using the heroku builds plugin to deploy the browser version (i.e. build locally, and upload a tar of your local dir). Since I also have a mobile version I ended up creating two .gitignore files, one for web and one for mobile, and toggle between them via a script. This way I can avoid committing the build files.

Answer (score 2):

Just want to add something on to Alex's answer. Make sure you either add `ionic-app-scripts` as a dependency (as opposed to devDependency), OR disable production mode in heroku via `heroku config:set NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false`

So, adding `"postinstall": "ionic-app-scripts build"` in the `scripts` section of package.json, and disabling production mode worked for me.